# Javascript countdown to hour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using the jQuery Countdown plugin created by Keith Wood, but I can't get it to work, I need to display how many hours, minutes and seconds are left till a certain time of the day (for example: 18:00:00).

The code inside the body tag:

```
<?php
$begintijd = $display['start'].":00:00";
?>
<script>
var begintijd = "<?php echo $begintijd ?>";
$(function () {
    var vandaag = new Date();
    werktijd = new Date(vandaag.getDay() begintijd);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: werktijd, format: 'HMS'});
});
</script>
```

$display['start'] returns in this situation with 18 (and the value is correct).

The code inside head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugin/js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugin/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
```

jQuery plugin file: http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.plugin.js

jQuery countdown file: http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js

Chrome says "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" on line:

```
werktijd = new Date(vandaag.getDay() 18:00:00);
```

I'm new to Javascript and any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I had a script which will work without any plugin, might be in use

**HTML**

```
<div id="days"></div>
<div id="hours"></div>
<div id="minutes"></div>
<div id="seconds"></div>
```

**Javascript & php**

```
<%php $begintijd = $display['start']; %>

$(document).ready(function(){  
    var timer = null,
        begintijd = "<%php echo $begintijd %>",
        endTime = new Date(); //time you want to end

   endTime.setHours(begintijd);
   endTime.setMinutes(0);
   endTime.setSeconds(0);
   endTime = (Date.parse(endTime)) / 1000;

    function makeTimer() {
        var now = new Date(),
            now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000),
            timeLeft = endTime - now;
       if(timeLeft > 0){
            var days = Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400),
                hours = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 3600),
                minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600 )) / 60),
                seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)));
           if (hours < "10") { hours = "0" + hours; }
           if (minutes < "10") { minutes = "0" + minutes; }
           if (seconds < "10") { seconds = "0" + seconds; }    

           $("#days").html(days + "<span>Days</span>");
           $("#hours").html(hours + "<span>Hours</span>");
           $("#minutes").html(minutes + "<span>Minutes</span>");
           $("#seconds").html(seconds + "<span>Seconds</span>");

      }else{
       clearInterval(timer);
       $("#seconds").html("<span>00Seconds</span>");
      }  
   }
timer = setInterval(function() { makeTimer(); }, 1000);
})
```

**JS Fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/69ax5j4L/

Comment: I'm getting 00Seconds displayed when I have this: var endTime = new Date(vandaag.getMonth, vandaag.getDate, vandaag.getYear, begintijd) I'm trying to get current date + 18:00:00

Comment: Probably coz `var vandaag = new Date();` this is current date and time, so timer will be 00. It should be a future date to count down to.

Comment: I can't get it to work, if only the date function could be easy like PHP's date function.. :/ can you show me the code which is what I need?

Comment: So your end date comes from php?

Comment: No, it used to come from Javascript, but I couldn't get it to work, 5 mins ago, I tried to use PHP's date function, but nothing get displayed when is type it like this: var endTime = new Date(<?php echo date("F") ?>, <?php echo date("d") ?>, <?php echo date("o") ?>, begintijd), //time you want to end

Comment: what is `begintijd` ?

Comment: var begintijd gets $begintijd's value. var begintijd = "<?php echo $begintijd ?>"; $begintijd = $display['start'].":00:00"; $display['start'] displays 18. So var begintijd should show 18:00:00 (it shows at what time the user needs to start working)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that below code wouldn't return a valid date either "???" being "," or "-" (I couldn't figure out what you where tryng to do):

```
var vandaag = new Date();
werktijd = new Date(vandaag.getDay() ??? begintijd);
```

So first step is to add a `console.log(werktijd) just after it to check if it returns a valid date (and, I figure out, if it is on current day).

Next check [Date() syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp).

If I'm not wrong, what you are trying to do is:

```
var vandaag = new Date();
// (EDIT) var begintijdHour = new Date(begintijd).getHours();
var begintijdTime = new Date(
    vandaag.toDateString()
    + " "
    +  begintijd
);

werktijd = new Date(
    vandaag.getFullYear(),
    vandaag.getMonth(),
    vandaag.getDay(),
    begintijTime.getHours(),
    begintijTime.getMinutes(),
    begintijTime.getSeconds()
);

// Checks:
console.log(vandaag); // Should output current time.
console.log(begintijdHour); // If shows NaN, then begintijd is much
    // probably not properly formatted as valid dateString input
    // (see below w3schools link).
```

**EDIT:** I edited below snipped after knowing that input lacks date part. Also modified last werktijd calculation to take in account minutes and seconds (if provided).

If you only want to take in account hour part (just as original code were doing), you can do it by simply using a regular expression. There is no need to convert *begintij* to Date() object. Simply calculate it as:

```
var begintijHour = begintij.replace(/:.*/, '');
```

Comment: I'm getting NaN, what do you mean with begintijd is much?
This code is meant to be for a page with "today's info". So you can see the remaining time till you have to go to your work (and the user needs to be there at 18:00)

Comment: much ...PROBABLY not properly formatted (...). Comment continues next line (I added a newline to avoid scrollbars).

That is `new Date(begintijd)` itself isn't returning a valid date because begintijd is (I figure out) not properly formatted. Can you show us a `console.log(begintijd)` output?

Comment: That's the problem: Date() requires full date input (date + time or at least date having time defaults to '0:00').